# Big_query SQL To have single row result instead of two rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im using Big Query Sql here
This is the table build
[image]
This table is showing customer id_123 has purchase in type_shop and delivery_shop & also delivery_home .

Is it possible for me to get the result to be reflect in a single row instead of 2 different rows ?
I only want to show this customer id_123 purchased in type_shop & uses delivery_home & delivery_shop in a row

I tried a few methods using array_agg(stru) but it is still shows 2 rows of result instead of 1.
Not sure what other SQL function should i try here ? try searching for similar content in stack overflow but there isnt one that i can apply .
[image]

Comment: you should provide a [mre], because why are there double math or science in the first place

Comment: @nbk edit my question "Both math and science are appearing twice is because in the first CTE (table_x) i did a left join on course_table"

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide your query? Is the 2nd image your expected output? Is it expected that there are still 2 rows for `id_456`?

Comment: @RiccoD , I used  ''' MAX(IF'shop' IN (type_group.type),1,0)) AS shop , # to call "1" if shop is being capture in type column , MAX(IF'pickup' IN (type_group.delivery),1,0)) AS pickup, # to call "1" if pickup is being capture in delivery column . Lastly i used ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(shop,online)) AS type_ & ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(pickup,home,shop) AS delivery . And yes id_456 should be 2 rows because this customer did a purchase in shop & online.  Im not too sure if by using MAX(IF) function is affecting the result to show type_shop twice since both MAX(IF) function is capturing 2 different column .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample data is your 1st table. Consider approach below:

```
with sample_data as (
  select 'id_123' as customer, 'm' as gender, [1,1] as type_shop, [0,0] as type_online, [0,0] as delivery_pickup,[0,1] as delivery_home, [1,0] as delivery_shop,
  union all select 'id_456' as customer, 'f' as gender, [1,0,1] as type_shop, [0,1,0] as type_online, [0,0,0] as delivery_pickup,[1,0,0] as delivery_home, [0,1,1] as delivery_shop,
),
normalize_data as (
select 
  customer,
  gender,
  type_shop[safe_offset(index)] as type_shop,
  type_online[safe_offset(index)] as type_online,
  delivery_pickup[safe_offset(index)] as delivery_pickup,
  delivery_home[safe_offset(index)] as delivery_home,
  delivery_shop[safe_offset(index)] as delivery_shop,
from sample_data,
unnest(generate_array(0,array_length(type_shop)-1)) as index
),
join_data as (
select 
  customer,
  gender,
  max(type_shop) as t_shop,
  max(type_online) as t_online,
  max(delivery_pickup) as delivery_pickup,
  max(delivery_home) as delivery_home,
  max(delivery_shop) as delivery_shop,
from normalize_data
  group by customer,gender,type_shop,type_online
)

select 
  customer,
  gender,
  array_agg(t_shop) as type_shop,
  array_agg(t_online) as type_online,
  array_agg(delivery_pickup) as delivery_pickup,
  array_agg(delivery_home) as delivery_home,
  array_agg(delivery_shop) as delivery_shop,
from join_data
  group by customer,gender
```

Output:

[image]